# How to retrieve image from Mysql and read it directly in image control asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, image

I stored a image as a byte[] array as blob datatype in MySQL, but I cant find proper way to read that same picture the other way in my asp.net application in image control. In the table "slike" there are 3 columns - image, imagename, brTablice - I was searching for an answer really long and yet didn't find any answers. Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Uid=Aleksa;port=3306;Pwd=pass;Database=projekat_automobili;";
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT image from slike where brTablice = 'BG-456-SD'", con);
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataReader DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (DR1.Read())
    {
        //TextBoxJmbg.Text = DR1.GetString(DR1.GetOrdinal("jmbg"));
        //TextBoxIP.Text = DR1.GetString(DR1.GetOrdinal("imeprezime"));
        //TextBoxTel.Text = DR1.GetString(DR1.GetOrdinal("tel"));

        byte[] imgg = (byte[])(DR1["image"]);
        if (imgg == null)
        {
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
            Image1.ImageUrl = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream).ToString();
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imgg);
            //Image1.ImageUrl = "";
        }
        else
        {
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
            Image1.ImageUrl = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream).ToString();
        }
    }


    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is part of project.

mysql table:

```
----------------------------
G_Picture| G_Picture_size |
----------------------------
0xsd/s45e| 9000           |
-----------------------------

uint FileSize = _sqldatareader.GetUInt32(_sqldatareader.GetOrdinal("G_Picture_size"));
                byte[] rawData = new byte[FileSize];
                _sqldatareader.GetBytes(_sqldatareader.GetOrdinal("G_Picture"), 0, rawData, 0, (Int32)FileSize);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(rawData);
                __G_Picture.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(ms);
```

Now you a bitmap picture.
hope this work.